# Use the chain rule to evaluate $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\displaystyle\int_{x^2-1}^{\sin(x)} \cos(t) \, \mathrm{d}t $

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, chain-rule

Doesn't the derivative of that integral just equal $\cos(x)$? What does it mean to use the Chain Rule? I know for sure it has nothing to do with $u$-substitution. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The derivative of $F(x)=\int_0^x \cos t\,dt$ is $\cos x$. Your function is $F(\sin x)-F(x^2-1)$.

Comment: You ought to take derivative of David's $F(sinx) - F(x^2-1)$ function and use chain rule to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some real $c$, one obtains
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{x^2-1}^{\sin x}\cos t \: dt = \frac{d}{dx}\int_c^{\sin x}\cos t \: dt-\frac{d}{dx}\int_c^{x^2-1} \cos t \: dt.$$
If $\phi(s) = \int_c^s \cos \: dt$, then 
$\int_{x^2-1}^{\sin x}\cos t \: dt = \phi(\sin x) - \phi(x^2 -1)$, thus 
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{x^2-1}^{\sin x}\cos t \: dt = \frac{d}{dx}\phi(\sin x) - \frac{d}{dx}\phi(x^2-1).$$
Now you see where the chain rule comes in?

Answer (score 4):

> Notice:
>
> $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\int_{y(x)}^{z(x)}f(t)\space\text{d}t\right]=f(z(x))\cdot\frac{\partial z(x)}{\partial x}-f(y(x))\cdot\frac{\partial y(x)}{\partial x}=f(z(x))z'(x)-f(y(x))y'(x)$$

So, we get:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\int_{x^2-1}^{\sin(x)}\cos(t)\space\text{d}t\right]=$$
$$\cos(\sin(x))\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\sin(x)\right)-\cos(x^2-1)\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x^2-1\right)=$$
$$\cos(x)\cos(\sin(x))-2x\cos(x^2-1)$$

Answer (score 3):

The fundamental theorem of calculus write $$\frac d{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t)\,dt=f(b(x))\, b'(x)-f(a(x))\, a'(x)$$ Now, for your case $$a(x)=x^2-1\implies a'(x)=?$$ $$b(x)=\sin(x)\implies b'(x)=?$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\int \cos t \, \mathrm{d}t = \sin t + \mathcal{C}$. You want the integral between $x^2 - 1$ and $\sin x$. That is, you want:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(\sin (\sin x) - \sin (x^2-1))$$

where you need to use the chain rule to differentiate this expression.

Comment: Being lazy, I should avoid the integration step. Cheers !